# Universal property of tensor products / Categorial expression of bilinearity

Tags: linear-algebra, category-theory

Let $V$ and $W$ be linear spaces. According to Wikipedia, the universal definition of the tensor product $V \otimes W$ satisfies the following property:

There is a bilinear map (i.e., linear in each variable $v$ and $w$) $\varphi : V\times W\to V \otimes W$ such that given any other vector space $Z$ together with a bilinear map $h:V\times W\to Z$, there is a unique linear map $\tilde{h}:V\otimes W\to Z$ verifying $h=\tilde{h}\circ \varphi$.

I am intrigued by this definition. The Cartesian product is supposed to have a categorial definition, which I have not comprehended so far, but the I have not seen a categorial definition of bilinearity. In this sense, the proposed categorial definition of tensor products seems to cheat.

Can somebody work out the tensor product in purely categorial terms?

Comment: I had the same thoughts. Have a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/q/626834/75923

Answer (score 4):

No, since this would mean that we have a notion of tensor product in every category (different from the cartesian product), which is not the case. What is the tensor product of two homotopy types? The notion of bilinearity really depends on the specific structure of our category of vector spaces. That being said, there is a quite general notion of bihomomorphisms in *concrete* categories and tensor products classifying them:

> B. Banaschewski and E. Nelson, Tensor products and bimorphisms, Canad. Math. Bull. 19 (1976) 385-401.

Notice that a bilinear map is not a map $V \times W \to Z$ of vector spaces, but rather a map $|V| \times |W| \to |Z|$ between the *underlying sets*, with additional properties. This explains the concreteness assumption.

There is also a notion of bihomomorphisms in monoidal categories. This has been studied by Anders Kock, Gavin Seal and others (see for example [arXiv/1205.0101](http://arxiv.org/abs/1205.0101)).

By the way, you should really understand cartesian products *before* tensor products or reading any of the mentioned papers.

Answer (score 1):

$\require{AMScd}$
I think your trouble comes from the fact that you are trying to see the diagram
$$\begin{CD} 
V \times W @>>> V\otimes W \\
@| @VVV \\
V \times W @>>> Z
\end{CD}$$
where horizontal maps are bilinear maps, inside the category of vector spaces over $k$. What you cannot.

What the universal property says is that the functor
$$ \mathrm{Bil}\, (V, W ; - ) \colon \mathbf{Vect}_k \to \mathbf{Set},\, Z \mapsto \{ k\text{-bilinear map } V\times W \to Z\} $$
is representable (by an object that we denote $V \otimes W$).

Answer (score 1):

I'm just pasting over what I just took the time to write [in my question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4718124/associativity-of-tensor-product-using-the-universal-property-and-not-elements) because I was thinking about this too recently.

**Categories Vect and Set:**
I assume that I have a category **Vect** whose objects are vector spaces and morphisms are linear maps, with a *forgetful functor* $\text{Fo}: {\bf Vect} \to {\bf Set}$, and that ${\bf Set}$ is a unital associative monoidal category under the cartesian product, $(X,Y) \mapsto X \times Y$. In particular below I'll use the unitor isomorphism $X \xrightarrow{i} \{\star\} \times X$. Note that the forgetful functor allows me to talk about when a function between vector spaces is a linear map, which I'll need below.

**Defininig bilinearity:** Now let's define *bilinear map*: Given three vector spaces $V$,$W$, and $Z$ in ${\bf Vect}$, a morphism $b: \text{Fo}(V)\times \text{Fo}(W) \to \text{Fo}(Z)$ is called bilinear if

1. for any choice of set function (i.e base point) $p: \{ \star\} \to \text{Fo}V$, the composition
   $$\text{Fo}W \xrightarrow{i} \{\star\} \times \text{Fo}W  \xrightarrow{p \times id} \text{Fo}V \times \text{Fo}W \xrightarrow{\text{Fo}b} \text{Fo}Z$$
   is in the image of the forgetful functor (i.e. is a linear map).
2. similarly for any choice of base point in $\text{Fo}W$ we have an analogous linear map.

**The universal property:**. We assume in ${\bf Vect}$ that for each pair of vector spaces $V$ and $W$ there exists a vector space $V \otimes W$ and a bilinear map $t: \text{Fo}V \times \text{Fo}W \to \text{Fo}(V \otimes W)$ satisfying:

For any vector space $Z$ and bilinear map $b: \text{Fo}V \times \text{Fo}W \to \text{Fo}Z$ there exists a unique linear map $L_b: V \otimes W \to Z$ making the induced triangular diagram in ${\bf Set}$ commute (i.e. $\text{Fo}(L_b) \circ t = b$).